# Single Sign On not working on one ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on

I have SSO set up across several company ASP.NET web apps. They all work fine expect one. This one app is a Silverlight application hosted in ASP.NET. This application is also edited in VS11 instead of VS2010 like the other sites. The every time I try to access this site it prompts for a password. Every site is on the same server. I have the following code on every web.config

```
  <authorization>
     <deny users ="?" />
     <allow users = "*" />
  </authorization>
  <machineKey  validationKey="935A714D87189B6077B0CC3C1B8AC0A2395F8373AC4037B3798F6AEC589FB0383A4C39640004E6BD7A0C9C0D8A1D5F17DC0525FC57377B5858AFB7AE640BF724"
                decryptionKey="B4E1A4285F1F96239047514F70386F9BB7A791F6976D32B22AFE7267A7287D54"
                validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

I am just very confused why this one application would require me to sign in again.

Comment: Did you reboot the server at least once? Have you tried access a single file, different from Silverlight (ie an image)?

Comment: @EmanueleGreco It is just basically a fancy spreadsheet, there are no files being hosted in that virtual directory other than the application.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you can serve up HTML, an image or blank .aspx page.

If the Siverlight app is accessing a local or network resource outside of the app pool permissions it will prompt.

Comment: I get prompted when I load the first page.

Comment: Does the silverlight use any resources to initialize?